# Task Scheduler ignores next run time

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012, task-scheduler, windows-server

So I have a very weird problem.

In Task Scheduler, I've setup my application to run every 15th minute. I've made sure to have all the correct settings and it runs under my credentials (entered a password):

[image]

And in my job overview, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see on the server time, the "Next run time" is simply ignored, and my program never runs.

What on earth is wrong here? How can it not run and just ignore my settings? :-)